# Disable RC4 ciphers best practice

Tags: rc4, ciphers

To be compliant with security best practices, we have a requirement to disable RC4 ciphers.

I have investigated a way to achieve this and, found that I can disable it by editing the registry keys.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
“Enabled”=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
“Enabled”=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
“Enabled”=dword:00000000
```

Also I have found that I can remove the cipher suites that contains RC4 by editing the GPO,  Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > **SSL Configuration Settings**,

My question is: What is the best way to remove support for a ciphers.  By deleting all the cipher suites that contain the cipher in the GPO or the only way to remove support for a cipher is via modifying the keys in regedit.

Comment: Remove support for a cipher from where? Remove support, or merely ensure that the cipher is not used? Please [edit] to clarify. Also, I'm not sure if this is really a good fit for our scope, or if it might be better asked on [su] or [sf]; I guess we'll see. Though kudos for adhering to [RFC 7465](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7465).

Comment: **Remove support for a cipher from where?** I need to avoid client computer and servers from using RC4, **Remove support, or merely ensure that the cipher is not used?** i dont understand what do you mean with remove support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RC4 is an algorythm, not some piece of software. It's the same difference between an idea and a book: you can attempt to suppress a book that carries a specific idea but you cannot suppress the idea itself.

Likewise, you cannot globally disable RC4 with a registry edit. At best, you will instruct software that reads that registry key not to use RC4.

Specifically, what you're doing with this registry entry (the GPO is just a way to propagate a registry edit to a domain) is instruct software that uses the Windows [secure channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx) API for establishing a TLS/SSL connection from using it **by default**. Software that do not use SChannel or software that do not let the SChannel subsystem auto-negociate an SSL connection will not be affected.

For instance, setting these registry entries will prevent an [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) web server from using the RC4 cipher but will do nothing about a [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) server.

**Conclusion**: it is impossible to globally prevent the use of RC4. You should refocus your question by specifying exactly what software you want to restrict. Such a question would be more suited, however, to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)